# Как настроить GIT для совместной работы Windows 10 + Windows Server 2012 + Linux

Tags: git

1. Все пытаюсь настроить удобную обвязку разработки. 
   Разработку веду на Windows 10. Там же есть локальный репозиторий из которого push-у в репозиторий на Linux, на котором весит сайт (пишу php скриптики все такое). Есть две ветки: master и development. На Linux аналогичная структура, но мне это не подходит, так как приходится всегда делать chekout ветки на Linux сервере, что бы закинуть изменения. Хотелось бы что то типо репозитория --bare,
   но у него другая структура (а я бы хотел после пуша заливать на Linux только продуктив без дополнительных заморочек, чтоб скриптик сразу можно было вызвать из браузера). Бывают ли какие-то более аккуратные решения?
2. Так же хочу пушить через SSH на Windows Server. С одной стороны вроде все ясно, но что-то я не понял как подключить вторую Remote. Допустим на Windows server будет создан git init --bare, то как пушить в два разных сервера (Linux и Windows server) из локального репозитория (windows 10)? Если кто сталкивался с такими штуками, подскажите где подсмотреть.

Comment: для сервера можно (нужно) настроить автодеплой, чтоб не заморачиваться каждый раз.. Смутило ваше `checkout чтобы закинуть изменения` - с каких пор переключение ветки изменения добавляет?

Comment: а насчет 2 ремотов.. делается это не трудно, но при этом вам всё-равно надо будет выбирать ветку/репозиторий для пуша, и так же, можно забыть про логическое разделение изменений на проект, так делать не советовал бы, в своё время пытался и понял что так лучше не делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно научить Git автоматически делать `git checkout` после пуша. Для этого вам нужен хук `post-receive` с примерно таким содержанием:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
GIT_DIR='.git'
git reset --hard
```

Также нужно разрешить Git принимать пуши в текущую ветку:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

(Так как вы уже пушите, значит вы уже дали такое разрешение).

Хуки живут в каталоге `.git/hooks`. [Более подробная инструкция.](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2011/git-deploy-made-simple/)

Answer (score 1):

**1 вопрос**

То что вы ищите, называется автодеплой. **sanmai** ответил, как можно сделать "выкатку изменений" с помощью хуков после пуша средствами git.

Еще можно использовать инструменты типа GitLab, но придется настроить деплой. По сути, GitLab будет делать то же самое, но более "аккуратно", как вы выразились. Работает из браузера.

Схематично будет выглядеть так: ваш стенд разработчика => GitLab (bare-репо) => рабочий сайт

**2 вопрос**

Можно сделать сколько угодно удаленных реп. Репы типа `bare` - это чисто хранилища (то, что хранится в каталоге `.git` не-bare репозиториев).

Не-bare (обычные) еще имеют рабочий каталог (это то, что исполняет ваш PHP), поэтому нужно постоянный `checkout` после пула, чтобы привести рабочий каталог в соответствие с хранилищем в `.git` каталоге.

Итак, вам нужно подключить дополнительные репозитории.

На стенде разработчика смотрим какие репы уже подключены:

```
git remote -v
```

Скорее всего там будет только один `origin`.

Добавление новых реп делается так:

```
git remote add windows-repo URI-windows-repo
```

- `windows-repo` - удобное для вас название
- `URI-windows-repo` - любой способ указания ссылки на репозиторий, [git поддерживает](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) ssh, git, http протоколы и ссылку на диске. В вашем случае будет ssh (а еще как вариант можно монтировать windows каталог к себе и пушить по файловому протоколу).

Затем снова можно посмотреть все репозитории через `git remote -v`.

Пушить надо так, вы это уже умеете:

```
git push windows-repo название-ветки
```

Пушить можно в два, 3, 4 ... репо, либо в один. Но каждый пуш делается индивидуально (`git push origin ...`, `git push windows-repo ...`), так как git-это распределенная система.